# How to store output variable into database field?

Tags: mysql, php

Here is my php code which runs `shell_exec` function to run linux based program. I am getting output. But I am not able to store it in to mysql database. Can anybody tell how to store $output variable into mysql database field?

Here is my code snippet. Please help me.

```
<?php
$old_path = getcwd();
echo "<pre>$old_path</pre>";
chdir('/home/abc/Downloads/ocr/');
$output = shell_exec('./ocr -d 2 -T /home/abc/Downloads/images/image1.jpg');
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: Have you try to redirect output of ocr to STDOUT to get it in output variable?

Comment: What is `./ocr`? Is it a shell script, ELF executable? What does it have to do with MySQL?

Comment: @remeo ninov : I haven't tried STDOUT.. I will try..

Comment: @JonathanBen-Avraham : ocr is a linux based program (optical character recognition). It reads character from Images. I want to save the output of ocr into Mysql..

Comment: I don't see any code related to connecting/inserting to MySQL in your sample. smth like this - http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.examples-basic.php

Comment: @shershen : i have just given shell_exec function code.. I haven't displayed connection code. I am asking for that how can I save my output in database. Because I tried writing insert query on the same page and I was getting error.. That's why I am asking for a help that what should I write to insert the output into database field.